# Questions about MQTT max message size

Tags: mqtt, industry-4.0, paho

I am using MQTT Paho, and I have 2 questions about it:

1. How many words can I send as a payload message? For example, can I send all lines below as one payload?

   ```
   O1000
   T1 M6
   (Linear / Feed - Absolute)
   G0 G90 G40 G21 G17 G94 G80
   G54 X-75 Y-75 S500 M3  (Position 6)
   G43 Z100 H1
   Z5
   G1 Z-20 F100
   X-40                   (Position 1)
   Y40 M8                 (Position 2)
   X40                    (Position 3)
   Y-40                   (Position 4)
   X-75                   (Position 5)
   Y-75                   (Position 6)
   G0 Z100
   M30
   ```
2. If any of these lines don't work, can I make it send message to the broker? These lines are G-Code of CNC machine. Usually, when any line isn't executed, the whole program will stop at that line. Is it the same with MQTT?

Comment: See this discussion [Max mqtt payload size #107](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/107) in the Eclipse Paho™ MQTT Python Client GitHub repository as well as [Max message size for embedded c? #75](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.embedded-c/issues/75). It seems to be setting dependent on the server side however an expected minimum is a couple of K bytes.

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking in your second question. Could you add more detail about what you want to know?

Answer (score 5):

First question:

The payload of the message is limited to 268,435,456 bytes (256Mb) (see the Stack Overflow question [*What is the maximum message length for a MQTT broker?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522053/what-is-the-maximum-message-length-for-a-mqtt-broker))

Your second question doesn't make sense, but basically assuming the whole g-code is in one message it will all be delivered or not. It's up to you how you to implement the taking a received message and passing it to the machine.

Comment: my second question is: is there any Technic to make the subscriber publish a message to broker when any of these lines  isn't executed by CNC machine . hardillb

Comment: That's up to you to implement, based on how you send commands to the machine and what responses it gives. We don't have access to the hardware so have no idea how it works